# Making range of characters not greedy in Regex

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I have a list of messages where I'm searching in that message for 4 or 3 digit number, I then replace it with that number.

So my current Regex is

Find

```
(.*)([0-9]{3,4})(.*)\r
```

Replace

```
\2
```

However, the problem is with [0-9]{3,4} only takes the first 3 digit if there are 4 digits, so even if there is a 4 digit number sequence, it will just grab a 3 digit number. Which is what I don't want.

Is there a way to make it grab a 4 digit number if it can and only grab a 3 digit number if it can't find the 4 digit number in that line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions have support for non-greedyness using the `*?` operator:

```
(.*?)([0-9]{3,4})(.*)\r
```

Depending on the program you use to match the regex, you will need to add additional flags.

In such case a regex is more happy to give a digit to the second group than to the first. By default regexes are greedy left-to-right: they will try to store everything in the first group and only move to the next if necessary (to still match the string).

Comment: Thanks for that it works. I didn't realise you make everything around it not greedy.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks, modified, althoug semantically this doesn't change anything: it is already the last group thus it is by default already the less greedy one.

Comment: Semantically yes, but it may slow a little the search if the regex engine isn't enough smart to automatically optimize (in this case to make greedy) something like `.*?\r` *(<= and note that the `\r` is not always a part of a newline sequence)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
(([0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}))
```

It will either take 4 digits, or 3 digits if it can't.